# I assign that.gridsportsRecordAll are becoming undefined. ---> that.gridsportsRecordAll = responsesportsRecord;

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, typescript

- I am new to js.
- I am getting values in responsesportsRecord but I am not able to assign in that.gridsportsRecordAll.
- when I assign that.gridsportsRecordAll are becoming undefined. ---> that.gridsportsRecordAll = responsesportsRecord;
- I am providing relevant code below and entire code in gist
- can you guys tell me how to fix.
- providing my code below

https://gist.github.com/niniyzni/5c19f385b35f9418086125799803efe7

```
 private gridsportsRecordAll: any = [];

 callGridLoadsportsRecord(responsesportsRecord) {
        let that = this;
        //if (responsesportsRecord.schedItems.length > 0) {
        if (responsesportsRecord > 0) {
           // response.sportsRecord.properties
            this.LionGridsportsRecord = responsesportsRecord;
            that.gridsportsRecordAll = responsesportsRecord;
            console.log("callGridLoadsportsRecord this.gridsportsRecordAll--->" , that.gridsportsRecordAll);
            this.gridsportsRecordLoad();
            //this.loadPreference(this.LionCreateVal.TigerNo);
        }
    }
```